# How does Fork work with PowerCharge-on-Crit work?

Tags: path-of-exile

The questin is about Projectiles caused by the Fork-support-gem: http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Fork

Will projectiels caused by Fork either have a

- unique crit, (so they could crit when the original didn't crit)
- shared Crit, (so they crit when the original spell did crit)

We have PCoC equipped: http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Power_charge_on_crit

So the big incentive:
Can these new Projectiles by Fork cause a Power Charge? Thus there was faster gain of Power Charges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each individual critical hit has a chance to grant you a power charge, but you can gain at most one per skill activation [(1)](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Power_charge_on_crit#Skill_Functions_and_Interactions).

The Forked projectiles will use the same critical strike roll as the original projectile. Attaching Fork will give you more chances to gain that power charge, but you'll still only get one at best. The Forked projectiles will only crit if the original one did (bar some exceptions such as if one of them hits a target with [Assassin's Mark](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Assassin%27s_Mark)).

In contrast, the [Voll's Protector](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Voll%27s_Protector) unique chest piece will give you one power charge for every enemy hit by a critical strike.

Comment: By the way: Does the same rule apply to LMP/GMP? - max one PC but higher chance?

Comment: @Raikan Yeah, same thing - even Multistrike / Spell Echo only allow one charge with PCoC